# How to Restrict PHP script to acess content outside the folder

Tags: php, architecture, filesystems

## System Design:

```
root/
     AllUsers/
             Folder1/
                    Script1
             Folder2/
                    Script2
     www/
        all acessablescript
```

## Conditions:

I don't want script1 to acess script2 or 2scripts can't perform any SQL query .

## How the system works:

I am creating a website wher user can store their files and creat folders just like Google drive .

### vulnerability

If an user e.g owner of `Folder1` upload a php file.
Which is gonna acess the DB and show perform some SQL queries  while previewing that file in browser , then I am suspecting that will show the query result or acess the user to see what is inside of `Folder2` ,mean other users file,photo etc.

Comment: "just like google drive" - Wouldn't it then be better to not execute uploaded php files at all?

Comment: How not to execute that.

Comment: Then how to say browser to paint it just like bunch of sentences.